# How to encrypt and decrypt a number using same key?

Tags: node.js, algorithm, encryption

I need a way to encrypt a number (say `3423234234`) using a secret key, which can also be decrypted using that same key.

```
const encrypted = encrypt(number, key)
const decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, key)
```

I tried [CryptoJS](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/) using AES, DES, Rabbit and RC4 algorithms, but it gives me a long encrypted value with special characters.

I want some encrypted value like MongoDB's `ObjectId` (which contains only alphanumeric characters like `1575866cab3f22f0c8510451f293f405`, and should not exceed `20` or `40` characters).

Comment: You can always convert string from crypto functions to base64 to avoid special characters. About hash - this is one way cryptography. And there is no way to recover original text from its hash

Comment: I used `hash` just give you an idea for encrypted value. I am talking about encryption and decryption not hashing. Converting to base64..but still it will be long.

Comment: Use base64 conversion to have only A-Za-z0-9

Comment: Have a look at [Format Preserving Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) which might help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way.

```
const  decrypt = function (num) {
    const base = "tGVwFAPiJqh3maNHdZfby9eIQXcr2zvgD57YMn8KWCxkSUujpB10sL6oRTl4OE"
    num = num.toString()
    let lastChar, baseConverted = 0, index=0;
    while(num !== ''){
        lastChar = num.slice(-1);
        baseConverted += base.indexOf(lastChar) * Math.pow(62,index);
        index++;
        num = num.slice(0, num.length-1);
    }
    return baseConverted;
};
const  encrypt = function (num) {
    const base = "tGVwFAPiJqh3maNHdZfby9eIQXcr2zvgD57YMn8KWCxkSUujpB10sL6oRTl4OE"
    // console.log(base.length)
    let mod, baseConverted = '';
    while(num){
        mod = num%62;
        baseConverted = base.slice(mod, mod+1)+baseConverted;
        num = Math.floor(num/62);
    }
    return baseConverted;
};

module.exports = {
    encrypt,
    decrypt
}
```

The reason I wanted it because I want to encrypt all the id's of a resource before sharing it with client. 
It will decrypt the keys when request is received.